# Record Component Video

Tags: video

I've found plenty of simple, cheap solutions for recording composite video sources to my PC, a laptop. But I'd like to be able to record in HD and use component cables.

I was wondering if anyone had a good solution for this.

Required:

```
Cheap
```

Desired

```
Portable, external hardware device
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your definition of cheap, but there is the [HD PVR](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_hdpvr.html) from Hauppauge which works well from ~ $200.